# Error Importing DB from SQL Azure to a localDB

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a SQLPaaS instance which we have exported into a `.bacpac` file. When I try and import the `.bacpac` into my local SQL Server 2017 CU14, I am getting an error on an ExternalDataSource, I do not need this external data source so I am trying to figure out a way to import this `.bacpac`.

I have tried using `sqlpackage.exe` (the import action doesn't let you exclude types, and the publish action requires a `.dacpac` not a `.bacpac`).

The error is:

> Error importing database:Could not import package.
>
> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'RDBMS'.
>
> Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script: CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [LocalLoopBack]
>   WITH (
>       TYPE = RDBMS,
>   LOCATION = N'xxxxxx.database.windows.net',
>   DATABASE_NAME = N'xxxxxxx',
>   CREDENTIAL = [xxxxxx]
>   );

Is there anyway I can get this to import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you copy that Azure SQL Database with a new name using Azure portal as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy#copy-a-database-by-using-the-azure-portal)?

[image]

Remove the external data source from the new database and then export it as bacpac. Delete the newly created database with the copy operation. Import the bacpac created to your localDB instance.

Comment: Yes I can and that's our process now, we have found we have to copy the DB first, since the export is not transactionally consistent, so we are already doing that. Its just a pain the amount of steps needed to pull a DB down to do local development. After I posted this I did, do this again and removed the external data source and it works

Comment: If you were using SQL Data Sync you may have to do a similar process. It is easy to migrate to Azure but not easy to return back.